# I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 200 into shape (64,64,1)

Tags: python, arrays, opencv

The code below is not complete, but at this point of execution in my jupyter notebook, I get error messages. (I am a newbie, so I request kindness, I will be grateful if someone can help):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
from random import shuffle
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_data = 'C:/Users/aege_/OneDrive/Documents/Conv/ImageData/Train'
test_data = 'C:/Users/aege_/OneDrive/Documents/Conv/ImageData/Test'

def one_hot_label(img):
    label = img.split('.')[0]
    if label =='BK':
        ohl = np.array([1,0])
    elif label == 'FK':
        ohl = np.array([0,1])
    return ohl

def train_data_with_label():
    train_images = []
    for i in tqdm(os.listdir(train_data)):
        try:
            path = os.path.join(train_data, i)
            img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            img = cv2.resize(img,(128, 128))

        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

        train_images.append([np.array(img), one_hot_label(i)])
    shuffle(train_images)
    return train_images

def test_data_with_label():
    test_images = []
    for i in tqdm(os.listdir(test_data)):
        try:
            path = os.path.join(test_data, i)
            img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            img = cv2.resize(img,(128, 128))

        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

        test_images.append([np.array(img), one_hot_label(i)])
    return test_images

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import *
from keras.optimizers import *

training_images = train_data_with_label()
testing_images = test_data_with_label()

tr_img_data = np.array([i[0] for i in training_images]).reshape(-1,64,64,1)
tr_lbl_data = np.array([i[1] for i in training_images])

tst_img_data = np.array([i[0] for i in testing_images]).reshape(-1,64,64,1)
tst_lbl_data = np.array([i[1] for i in testing_images])
```

When executed, I get the following two error messages.

> OpenCV(3.4.2)
>   C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1534379934306\work\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4044:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
>
> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 200 into shape (64,64,1)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Please take a moment to review [this helpful guide on how to get the most out of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It would be helpful if you describe what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Looks like you have only 200 data points that you are trying to reshape as a 64x64 matrix. There aren't enough points to reshape into that dimension.

Comment: Like @Nivi said, it looks like you only have 200 elements in your array, which can't be reshaped into that shape. I suggest you work through your image sizes and any transformations you are making to them on paper to be sure that you understand just what dimensions you have to work with at each step.

Comment: Yes for training set, I have only 200 images in total, of 2 classes with 100 each. For test set I have 25 of each class (total 50 for test set).. 

I got these 250 pics of Eyes (for 2 eye disease) from my hospital. How would I get the right shape ? Do I have to get the shape of each image ?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things that I consider weird in your code and these lead to your error, since you consider yourself a newbie, maybe I should point them out.

1) First of all, are you sure that you want to open your images in grayscale, most image networks preform better on color images, but normalized, between the values of -1 and 1.

2) Right now the matrix of your grayscale image is probably 128x128, instead of 128x128x1, a good and clear practice would be np.expand_dims(image, -1) to add that third dimension.

3) don't load all your images into memory, write a simple generator. and don't append your array in a list, use `np.stack()` try:

```
 np.stack((np.zeros((128,128,1)), np.zeros((128,128,1)))).shape
```

and see the output, to understand how.

These tips should help you fix your bug, if not, tell me and I'll give you a code example of a generator for your example. But try yourself first, learning is important :)

EDIT

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from random import shuffle


def generator(batch_size):
    """
    The generator that supplies all bottleneck files
    :param batch_size: (int) the batch size, or amount of data that will be yield every call.
    :yield (list) the training batch list(input_image, input_label)
    input_image = the image to feed to the nn
    input_label = the one hot encoded labels
    """
    def prepare_batch(data_batch):
        """
        Method that provides the proper data to be fed to the nn
        :param data_batch: (list) list as yielded by the generator
        :return: (np.ndarray, np.ndarray) the images and labels
        This method is executed in train.py but can be executed in the generator, so that it is yielded
        """
        batch_images, batch_labels = zip(*data_batch)
        batch_images = np.array(batch_images, dtype=np.float32)
        batch_labels = np.array(batch_labels, dtype=np.float32)
        return batch_images, batch_labels

    batch = []
    files = [os.path.join('data/2ca1eb3ace', f) for f in os.listdir('data/2ca1eb3ace')]
    shuffle(files)
    for image_file in files:
        img = cv2.imread(image_file, 0)  # change to cv2.imread(image_file, 0) if you want to work with color imqaes
        img = cv2.resize(img, (64, 64))  # 64 x 64 matrix
        img = np.expand_dims(img, -1)  # expand last axis, 64 x 64 x 1 matrix

        batch.append([img, [0, 1, 1, 1]])  # random label = [0, 1, 1, 1]
        if len(batch) == batch_size:
            generated_batch = batch
            batch = []
            # yield will pause the code and continue on the next for loop iteration on the next call
            yield prepare_batch(generated_batch)  



for images, labels in generator(10):
    print(images.shape, labels.shape)  # 10x64x64x1 for the images; when you use generator(20) you get 20x64x64x1
```

It isn't the prettiest code, but I didn't use python for a long time, is this the functionality you want?

Comment: Hi T.Kehler, Let me try it out first.

Comment: I don't understand where to insert "np.expand_dims(image, -1)" in the code as you said. And I also do not know where to insert "np.stack((np.zeros((128,128,1)), np.zeros((128,128,1)))).shape" . Pls help. I have been confusing myself.